# disable/enable lights/objects depending on render engine

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Can i somehow enable/disable lights/objects depending on render engine?

e.g. sun should be disabled on cycles, a plane with emission should be enabled only on cycles.

On EEVEE the sun should be enabled and the plane with emission should be disabled.

The only idea i have i disabling it with driver and python. Is there an easier way?

Comment: that would be a great option, or create a light collection for each engine

Comment: @moonboots: good idea...but i have still have no idea how to automate this. I wish there would be a Blender handler for render engine change....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @moonboots, having two different collections holding your lights is the best option by far. Easy, robust, quick.

The only thing that I would add (optionally) are few lines of code in case I wanted to have more control over it (separate it to different scenarios maybe, keep track of different groups of lights etc).

Which I guess is an over-killer but here we go:

first things first, is always good to know which render engine are you on

and this one gives always the correct answer:

bpy.context.scene.render.engine

next you may want to enable and disable certain Collections or even objects if you like.

What I would do to anticipate this is to use a prefix for my objects/groups or collections. Something similar to EV_nameofmylight for my EEVEE light objects and on the other hand something like CY_nameofmylightobject for the CYCLES lights.

then a quite dirty but an effective way to toggle them would be to parse the whole collection of my objects (notice here that if you disabled a light in purpose its state will be ignored and it will be enabled again). So we have already a small bug to deal with.

The code should look something like this:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
render_engine = bpy.context.scene.render.engine

#exceptions is an optional list where you may put the names of the lightobjects that you want to remain unchanged 
#is not that useful if you consider that you may always remove the suffix (CY or EV) by the object's name instead
exceptions = []


for obj in scn.objects:
    if render_engine == 'BLENDER_EEVEE':
        if 'CY_' in obj.name and obj.name not in exceptions:
            obj.hide_render = True
            #obj.hide_viewport = True
            obj.hide_set(True)
        if 'EV_' in obj.name and obj.name not in exceptions:
            obj.hide_render = False
            #obj.hide_viewport = False
            obj.hide_set(False)
    elif render_engine == 'CYCLES':
        if 'CY_' in obj.name and obj.name not in exceptions:
            obj.hide_render = False
            #obj.hide_viewport = False
            obj.hide_set(False)
        if 'EV_' in obj.name and obj.name not in exceptions:
            obj.hide_render = True
            #obj.hide_viewport = True
            obj.hide_set(True)
```

Comment: I would suggest iterating through a list of pairs of (render engine name, prefix) rather than the if statement for those people who use add-on render engines like renderman.

Comment: Sure, that would be also useful. Feel free to alter the code to your taste!